# New Line Command ("\n") Doesn't Working While Reading Files (Android) java

Tags: java, android, string, file, command-line

```
      String mystring="Hello"+"\n"+ "World" ;

        writeToFile(mystring);
        String newstring = readFromFile();
        mytextview.setText(newstring);
```

**my text view just shows "HelloWorld"  without newline**

**I Couldn't understand why It doesn't recognizes "\n"**

**These are my writetofile and readfromfile functions;**

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
         try {
         OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myfilename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
         outputStreamWriter.write(data);
         outputStreamWriter.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
        // Log.e(TAG, "File write failed: " + e.toString());
         }
         }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private String readFromFile() {
         String ret = "";

         try {
         InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("myfilename");

         if ( inputStream != null ) {
         InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
         String receiveString = "";
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

         while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
         stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
         }

         inputStream.close();
         ret = stringBuilder.toString();
         }
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         //Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
         } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
         }
         return ret;
         }
```

what I am trying to do is saving a string to phone's internal storage and read back the same string .

Comment: try `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `\n`

Comment: and depending what he is reading it back with his editor may just not represent "\n" ...

Comment: Your question is, "If I concatenate all the lines of my file, why are all the lines of my file concatenated?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are using the BufferedReader, check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) for readLine()
it states:

> Returns the next line of text available from this reader. A line is represented by zero or more characters followed by '\n', '\r', "\r\n" or the end of the reader. **The string does not include the newline sequence.**

you could manually add it back in your while loop, or use another readXYZ method.

Comment: thank you very much. It was a quick solve :) 

manually adding the "\n"'s worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution as suggested by Su-Au Hwang by this way

addded manually \n by replacing ordinary \n

```
 String[] strLines = new String[lines.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            lines.set(i, lines.get(i).replace("\\n","\n"));
            strLines[i] = lines.get(i);
        }
        return strLines;
```